# Navigating to a new activity on clicking an image in android apps

Tags: android

I am just a beginner in Android application. I need to navigate to a new activity on clicking an image. Till now i donot have anything in my new activity. Just i simply want to navigate it.

My xml is:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagelanding"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/andreis_landing" />
```

My java file by default is:

```
public class MainViewActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_view, menu);
    return true;
}

   }
```

So now on clicking the image i want to navigate to another activity which is saved as MainMenu.java

Comment: It is the simplest thing in Android, i think that you should follow some tutorials instead of asking these basic things here on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first initialize the imageview

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
 ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagelanding); //
 iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {
           public void onClick(View v)
           {
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainViewActivity.this,MainMenu.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           } 
 });
```

1. Initialize imageview
2. Write a click listener for imageview
3. In onClick start the activity using intent
4. Make sure you declare all activities in manifest file

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA how can i help u

Comment: I am working on Open Gls. but got one problem. can u help me in this?

Comment: @Raghunandan hey sorry actually i thought we can accept 2 answers and as i got the other answer also correct so i accepted it also and i didnt use this site before much so i dont know that 2 answers cannot be accepted

Comment: @Raghunandan i think u gave me a downvote for that reason. Its very silly man

Comment: @bhaku no i din't but i downvoted you other question of manifest. Yes you can't accept 2 answers. You should accept the best possible solution and voted to close the question

Comment: @Raghunandan ok fine anywys i have just started learning android and java is also new to me and i work in a very small IT company and i am assigned to build an app in a week so i take help from this site

Comment: @bhaku taking help is fine but you need to show some effort before asking a question. If there is something that you don't understand or run into trouble then you should ask a question with details. Your previous question lacked such detail

Comment: @Raghunandan ok thanks for your help anywys. So you working in bangalore?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50126/discussion-between-bhaku-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MainViewActivity extends Activity {

private Imageview image;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_view);

  image = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.imagelanding);
  image.setOnCLickListener(didClickImageView)
}

private onClickListener didClickImageView =  new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenu.java);
                        startActivity(intent);     
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 3):

write somethig like this in onCreat

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagelanding);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainViewActivity.this,Activity2.class));

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewByid(R.id.imagelanding);
iv.setOnClickListener(new OnclickListener{
@override 
public void onClick{
startActivity(new Intent(MainViewActivity.this,MainMenu.class));
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ImageView imagView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagelanding);
imagView .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {
           public void onClick(View v)
           {
               Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           } 
 });
```